# Overcoming 8000 limit in openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdx, teradata

I need to access Teradata database from MS SQL Server through openrowset. But my script has more than 8000 characters (actually almost twice as many). Here is script example:

```
select * from openrowset('MSDASQL','DWH'; 'login'; 'pass', 
'select * FROM DATABASE.TABLE')
```

I tried to overcome this limit, by dividing script in two parts, and then use EXEC command:

```
DECLARE
@strSQL1 varchar(8000),
@strSQL2 varchar(8000)

SELECT
@strSQL1 = 
'select * from openrowset(''MSDASQL'',''DWH''; ''login''; ''pass'', ',
@strSQL2 = 
'''select * FROM DATABASE.TABLE'')'

EXEC (@strSQL1 + @strSQL2)
```

But this doesn't work, because still SQL command inside openrowset statement is longer than 8000 characters.

I would normally create view or stored procedure on Teradata database, and then fire it up, but I have no permission to do it.

Anyone know how to do it right? I tried almost everything.

Comment: split logic into 2 `Exec`s and then join the results up at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @strSQL1 varchar(8000);
DECLARE @strSQL2 varchar(8000);

SELECT
@strSQL1 = 
 'select * from openrowset(''MSDASQL'',''DWH''; ''login''; ''pass'', ',
@strSQL2 = 
 '''select * FROM DATABASE.TABLE'')';

DECLARE @SQLbig varchar(MAX);
SET @SQLbig = '';
SET @SQLbig = @SQLbig + @strSQL1;
SET @SQLbig = @SQLbig + @strSQL2;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLbig;
```

p.s. *not* using semi-colons will be deprecated in a future release of `sql-server`